# Cloud Run deploy to GKE cannot change URL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

When we create a cloud run service and run it on GKE it does not seem to be possible to change the URL or to map a custom domain to the service.

The domain is currently http://stacko-gke.default.example.com
and the service is https://console.cloud.google.com/run/detail/cluster/us-central1-a/crun/default/stacko-gke/metrics?project=stack-123456

We had to use the CURL trick to specify a host header and that worked, but I would need to be able to change the host for DNS to work properly, please advise.

Comment: Note: For Cloud Run and for most services behind a proxy, you need to specify the HTTP Host header. This is also an HTTP requirement for HTTP 1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options on Cloud Run:

1. Create a domain mapping for each Service, and map your DNS: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains

If you are using HTTPS, the following considerations apply:
For Cloud Run, a managed certificate for HTTPS connections is automatically issued when you map a service to a custom domain. Note that provisioning the SSL certificate should take about 15 minutes. You cannot upload and use your own certificates.

2. Change the base domain from `example.com` to your own domain https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/default-domain and create a wildcard A record (*) pointing to the IP address of your `istio-ingressgateway`.

For Cloud Run on GKE, only HTTP is available by default. You can install a wildcard SSL certificate to enable SSL for all services mapped to domains included in the wildcard SSL certificate. For more information see [Enabling HTTPS](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/enabling-cluster-https).

You can map **multiple** custom domains to the same Cloud Run service such as example.com or www.example.com

Comment: It looks like you've taken my answer from the issue tracker. :) If you asked here, I would've answered as well.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google feel free to do so, there is still time for it. For community self- answers we need to wait 2 days until we can accept it.